# Prevent iCloud Photos Folder Being Auto-Created?

Tags: windows-10, icloud

I have iCloud for Windows *v7.0.1.210* on Windows 10 *version 1703*. I only enabled *iCloud Drive* and *web bookmark sync* features. But somehow the *iCloud Photos* folder is created automatically every time I open the *iCloud setting* after I deleted it manually, especially annoyingly it got added to my Quick access list inside File Explorer.

BTW, anyway to remove the iCloud icon from system tray on windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

iCloud Photos is pinned to Quick Access automatically, every time that iCloud is started. 
 Here is a discussion on preventing "iCloud Photos" from being added to Quick Access.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8015861

Basic steps:

- Open regedit
- Search for "{F0D63F85-37EC-4097-B30D-61B4A8917118}" (no quotes) — keys only
- Delete all occurrences that you find (four for me)

This worked for me.  I'm not sure if updates to iCloud will add these keys back in the registry.  I added commands to a clean-up script that I have that runs periodically to make sure that they are deleted automatically if they are added back.